# Using PCA on Train and testset

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pca

I'm trying to reduce the number of features I using in my Tensorflow model. For That I'm trying to use the PCA. here the code that I've wrote:

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn import preprocessing
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

number_of_PCA = 20



# Reading csv file
training_file = 'Training.csv'
testing_file  = 'Test.csv'
dataframe_train = pd.read_csv(training_file)
dataframe_test  = pd.read_csv(testing_file)
#Training values
features_labels_train = dataframe_train.columns.values[:-2]
class_labels_train    = dataframe_train.iloc[:,-2]
feature_values_train  = dataframe_train.iloc[:,:-2]
train_onehot          = dataframe_train.iloc[:,-1]

#Test values
feature_labels_test = dataframe_test.columns.values[:-2]
class_labels_test    = dataframe_test.iloc[:,-2]
features_values_test = dataframe_test.iloc[:,:-2]
test_onehot          = dataframe_test.iloc[:,-1]


#values standardisation
stdsc = preprocessing.StandardScaler()
np_scaled_train = stdsc.fit_transform(feature_values_train)
np_scaled_test  = stdsc.transform(features_values_test)

pca = PCA(n_components=number_of_PCA)
X_train_pca = pca.fit_transform(np_scaled_train) # This is the result 
X_test_pca  = pca.transform(np_scaled_test)

......................................................
```

When I run the Tensorflow on result, I get a big overfitting as shown bellow : 
[image]

I'm assuming that the way I'm using the PCA on the test set is the the issue.
Does anyone here has an idea what I'm missing here ?

Comment: I don't understand why you're computing the principal components only on the train set. You should try to fit and transform your PCA on the whole dataset, then split it between training and testing sets. Here, the components computed by the PCA are optimized for your training set only, and then blindly applied to your test set.

Comment: So just to make sure I get you right on this one. I need to merge both Training and Test set  and then split the result of PCA back ?

Comment: Yep, that's it! It should make more sense. Maybe the components computed with the training set are not really good for elements in the testing set. On a side note, overfitting could occurs for a lots of reason, but for this kind of questions crossvalidated is the place to go :)

Comment: Thanks for u're comment I'll try this, you could put it as answer I'll accept it

Comment: @Nizil But that wouldn't be a valid real-world case, since your test set won't be known, right?

Comment: Agree with mkaran here. @Nizil, this is not how one should proceed with transforming the train and test data. You should always only fit (find the coefficients, weights, transforms etc) on training data and just apply them on test data.

Comment: @Engine what does the blue and orange curves in the image depict?

Comment: You are processing correctly, and should not follow what Nizil said. The only thing you should watch out for is the training_file = 'Training.csv' and testing_file = 'Test.csv' dont have highly correlated data. And you can use cross-validation to check the overfitting problem.

Comment: @VivekKumar   the blue is the training and orange is test, but overfitting is good training and bad result by the test set

Comment: Ahh yes. Sorry my bad. To tackle this case, you can use cross-validation as I said in my previous comment. There can be many possible explanations for this. Maybe the model is not good for this type of data. Maybe the test data is too much far from training data. Maybe you need to optimize the parameters.

Comment: But as far as this question is concerned, you are doing the correct thing. This is how it should be.

Comment: @mkaran My bad, I totally agree that wouldn't be a valid real-world case. I'm currently working with a tiny dataset, and so use all data available to compute more robust components. I think the important point here is to have a training set with a distribution of the samples as close as possible to reality, otherwise the PCA won't perform nicely.

Comment: @Nizil I've tried your suggestion but there could see any change I guess that the issue here isn't the the way I use PCA. So I need to handel the overfiting as a separat problem

Comment: You can compare the component obtained with both methods, in my case results have some non-negligeable differences, but I suspect your training set to be big enough. Good luck with the tuning of your hyper-parameters :)